# How do I differentiate this complicated function? (The Poisson equation for the isothermal sphere)?

Tags: differential-equations

Ignore the first part of the question. Look at part ii. I understand how to solve basic differential equations in python, but when you have a nested differential I get quite confused. Please help

[image: The Question...]

Comment: You do understand that the first-order system and the small-x approximation of part i) is to be used in part ii), that is, part i) is the answer to your question on part ii)? // I would use a different first-order system using the nested structure, set `z=x^2*d(ln y)/dx`, then `y'=z*y/x^2` and `z'=-6*x^2*y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use a different first-order system using the nested structure of the given equation, set `z=x^2*d(ln y)/dx`, which implies `z(0)=0` for the assumed-as-non-singular solution `y`, then

```
y'=z*y/x^2
z'=-6*x^2*y
```

At `x` close to zero we have by the initial condition `y` close to `1` so that the second equation integrates in the lowest degree terms to `z=-2*x^3`. Inserted into the first equation this gives indeed `y=1-x^2`. One could now continue to compute higher-degree terms...

Now use the standard tools of python-scipy as demonstrated in the documentation or any other source for, among others, the popular Lorenz model as example of a multi-dimensional coupled system, leading to a code of

```python
x = np.logspace(-1,3,500)
x0 = x[0]
y0 = 1-x0**2
z0 = -2*x0**3

def odesys(x,u):
    y,z = u
    return z*y/x**2, -6*x**2*y

u = odeint(odesys, [y0,z0], x, tfirst=True, atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-11)
y,z = u.T
```

Putting the computed solution into a loglog plot along with a plot of `x^-2` gives the graphs

[image]

which shows the claimed trend.